# Error inflating ListView Binary XML line 0#

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

```
01-29 21:55:22.330 30653-30653/com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser, PID: 30653
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser/com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                 at com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1504)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                              Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Can't find ColorStateList from drawable resource ID #0x7f070059
                                                                                 at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadColorStateList(ResourcesImpl.java:980)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:1007)
                                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:531)
                                                                                 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4501)
                                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:578)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:246)
                                                                                 at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:842)
 01-29 21:55:22.330 30653-30653/com.example.mickeyt.onyxbrowser E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:163)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:159)
                                                                                 at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:155)
                                                                                    ... 30 more
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_history_layout"
android:layout_width="275dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:elevation="10dp"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
android:background="@drawable/history_layout">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/b_Toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/history_toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_HistoryList"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="History"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_HistoryClose"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/b_HistoryClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onHistoryClose"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/close" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="onHistoryDelete"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/delete" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/b_HistoryList"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="443dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@drawable/history_listview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/b_Toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
UrlHistoryAdapter adapter = new UrlHistoryAdapter(this);
    b_HistoryList.setAdapter(adapter);
    url = w_SearchBar.getText().toString();

    /*
    Webview
     */
    m_WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            UrlHistoryAdapter.add(url);
            UrlHistoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });
```

I don't know what to do for this issue, it started after I added a CustomArrayAdapter plus a ArrayList to my ListView for populating it. I have had zero success and without the populating of the ListView the feature is useless. Im wondering if it something to do with the XML file or the  Java file. Theres not much to the adapter besides the file which is fairly basic for the CustomArrayAdapter. All its used for is inputing a string and displaying it to a listview.

Ive searched around for answers and found some of similar issues, but there methods haven't worked and am resorting to having to post my own question regarding it. 
e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `android:backgroundTint="@drawable/history_listview"` in **`ListView`**. There is no background attached to **`ListView`**

> `android:backgroundTint` applies the color filter to the resource of
>   `android:background` when used together with
>   `android:backgroundTintMode.`

Try to set background then apply color filter to it.